# Convert your views into a custom module

Tags: views, theming, 6

I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 3 on Drupal 6.

A while back I read an article how you can take your views and put it in your "custom' module folder (granted you've set this up for custom theme functions). I haven't had much need for it lately, but recently I've been doing a lot of work for a client that has needed a bunch of reworking of their Views and CSS related to them. This has turned into a bit of a nightmare trying to make sure that they then take my exported views from my development server to their server and import them correctly (sometimes they rename them, sometimes settings are not exported for whatever reason, etc).

A while back a read an article about converting your views into modules and it seemed pretty straight forward, but now I can't find it. Could anyone point me in the right direction? All I could find is a 50 minute long video tutorial, and I would rather just have an article I can skim.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The below link seems like it should work, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It just dumps all the views export code at the top of the page. What I did:

Put this into my "sitetheme.module"

```
function sitetheme_views_api() {
   return array(
      'api' => 3,
  );
}
```

Created this separate file named "sitetheme.views_default.inc". Which I put in this code:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_views_default_views().
 **/
function sitetheme_views_default_views(){
  $files = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('module', 'sitetheme'). '/views',     '.view');
  foreach ($files as $filepath => $file) {
  require $filepath;
  if (isset($view)) {
 $views[$view->name] = $view;
  }
 }
  return $views;
}
```

Then I made a new folder in my sitetheme module called "views", took the export code and saved it something like "myexportview.view" and saved it under the "views" folder.

Then when I upload these files to the client server it just dumps all the code at the top of the admin/build/views page.

Any idea what I did wrong? I seem to be following the directions exactly but I'm not sure what I'm missing...

---

It appears that I had to put a `<?php` at the top of the `myview.view` export file. However, now Drush doesn't work... I get a fatal error from Drush when I try to clear the cache:

> Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /Users/mycomputer/Sites/mysite/htdocs/includes/common.inc on line 1733

Comment: http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/matt_cheney/howto_best_practices_embedding_views_code is a good one

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Views 3 on Drupal 6 and this method doesn't seem to work for me. When I do this method it just seems to dump all the view export data at the top of the views window then never get's implemented under admin/build/views . If I refresh the page the view export data dissapears.

Comment: It should be sitetheme_views_default_views() not sitetheme_views()

Comment: The file should also be in sitetheme.views_default.inc not sitetheme.views.inc unless you are including it directly from sitetheme.module.

Comment: I'll edit my top comment, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: do each of your export files start with `<?php` or do you just have all the $view->.... code in there?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the export from views then saved it with the ".views" extension.

Comment: they have to start with `<?php` just like the rest of the php files you have

Comment: Ok, that tutorial didn't mention that. I just got put on another project but I'll try it in a few minutes. Thank you for answers and I hope that's it because this would be a huge time saver for me.

Comment: If I put a "<?php" at the top of the exported view data (the 'myview.view' under /views of my module" I get a fatal error. I updated then tried clearing the caches and I get: Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /Users/ardtemp/Sites/harris_uchicago/htdocs/includes/common.inc on line 1733
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                           [error]
Error: __clone method called on non-object in

Comment: Oh, but oddly it doesn't crash the site and the view import works :-). However, Drush no longer works :(...

Comment: Not sure what's going on, as all of this works fine here but I don't use drush so maybe it's upset about something.  Just make sure each file that contains php starts with `<?php` (Like sitetheme.views_default.inc)

Answer (score 4):

When the Bulk Export module (part of the Chaos Tools Suite module) is enabled, it exposes a page (admin/structure/bulk-export) where views can be exported.

What you need to do is selecting the views you want to export, enter the short name of the module that will contain the views, and click on the "Export" button.

[image: screenshot]

The page that will appear next contains three text area fields (`<module name>` is the short name you entered in the previous page):

- One is for the content to place in `<module name>.info`
- The second is the content to place in `<module name>.module`
- The last is the content to place in `<module name>.views_default.inc`

The differences I can see between the code the module tells me to use, and the one you are showing are:

- The implementation of `hook_views_api()` is the following.

  ```
  /**
   * Implements hook_views_api().
   */
  function sitetheme_views_api($module, $api) {
    if ($module == 'views' && $api == 'views_default') {
      return array('version' => 2);
    }
  }
  ```
- The implementation of `hook_views_default_views()` is the following.

  ```
  /**
   * Implements hook_views_default_views().
   */
  function sitetheme_views_default_views() {
    $views = array();

    $view = new view();

    // …

    return $views;
  }
  ```

`$views` is an array of objects of the `view` class.